# How does one prove that the complete  intersection of a quadric and a cubic of $\mathbb P^5$ is unirational?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, fano-varieties, reference-request

The question is stated in the title, but I would like to add some motivation.

I've been teaching a course on complex tori and abelian varieties this semester and I would like to end it by showing some significant application of abelian varieties in algebraic geometry. I've come across a very beautiful  recent proof by Beauville that a certain specific sextic threefold as in the title is not rational and I have decided give an outline of it in my last lecture. Beauville refers to a paper of Enriques of 1912 for the proof of unirationality. I've got Enriques paper but I cannot make sense of it, so I'm looking either for another reference or for a sketch of proof.

Just in case it helps, here's  what I've been able to understand from Enriques' proof. Let $V_6=Q_2\cap C_3$ be the threefold, where $Q_2$ is a smooth quadric and $C_3$ a smooth cubic.  Let $P\in V_6=Q_2\cap C_3$ be a point. Then  $Q_2$ contains two families of planes through $P$, each parametrized by a $\mathbb P^1$. If $H$ is such a plane $H\cap C_3$ is a plane cubic $C_H$ and we can associate with $P$ the residual intersection $Q_H$ with $C_H$ of the tangent line to $C_H$ at $P$. As $H$ varies in one of the families of planes through $P$, $Q_H$ describes a rational curve $K$ in $V_6$. Of course, as $P$ varies, the curves $K$ fill up $V_6$. At this point, Enriques just claims that the curves $K$ thus defined ``correspond to the lines through a point in $\mathbb P^3$''.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can look at the short paper by Conte, Marchisio end Murre [*On the k-unirationality of the cubic complex*](http://cab.unime.it/mus/429/) (2007).

It contains a proof of the unirationality of $V_6$ over a field $k$ of any characteristic $\neq 2,3$, under the assumption that $V_6$ has a $k$-rational point $p$ and that one of the two planes through $p$ on the quadric is also rational over $k$.

In the introduction, the authors write "we follow closely Enriques construction, our only contribution being to fully explain and justify his statements".

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT:** here is a short, but non-elementary argument to prove that the threefold in question is uniruled:

The canonical class of your complete intersection is $(-6+2+3)H=-H$ where $H$ is the hyperplane section. Therefore this is a Fano and hence uniruled by the [Miyaoka-Mori criterion](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1971387), which is essentially an application of Bend and Break.

Comment: Thank you, Sándor. You are completely right: 1) I did not know the Miyaoka-Mori  criterion, and 2) actually I am looking for an elementary proof, specific to the situation.

The MM criterion says Fano varieties are uniruled. How does one show that they are actually unirational?


Comment: Oh, sorry. I was sloppy. I was thinking uniruled all the way. So, this is not an answer after all. Sorry!

Comment: I now feel obligated to think about this, but only tomorrow. That is, after I sleep a little. (I've just realized it is already tomorrow).... 

Comment: As you can see, Francesco found a reference. Thanks again!